# Getting a live preview of TeX (on Windows) - for just a small snippet of code?

Tags: editors, windows, wysiwyg

I wish to have a quickly updating work area so to be able to learn my LaTeX faster.

From reviewing the answers on [tex.stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com), and from going through the list of TeX editors [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) - I understand that no (free) editor (on Windows) to date can offer live preview of how my TeX code will look.  That is except LyX, but it doesn't allow my to write TeX code, but to only see what LyX produces.

A reasonable compromise for me would be to get a live preview of how just a small snippets of TeX code will look like.

I found one such solution online on [codedogs.com](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). Are there any other recommended solutions? (online or for the desktop)

Comment: Although [Gummi](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/) doesn't have a Windows version yet, the website indicates that a Windows version is on the way. Gummi has [live preview](http://gummi.midnightcoding.org/?page_id=2). Keep checking the site; Gummi is fantastic.

Comment: [Led](http://www.latexeditor.org/) was capable of doing that but it is not supported any more and contains a few nasty bugs. If you want to use it for testing codes but not valuable information editing, I would say it's the right choice.

Comment: Just noticed Gummi (link above) released a beta version for Windows a several weeks ago. I'm not so fond of the newer version but you might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

[TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) has this feature of snippet preview inlined right in your source.  I find it very useful.  It can do live preview updates too, I think, but this wasn't always working for me.  Plus it's a free software (as in beer and freedom) and multiplatform.

Comment: For live previews in TexStudio, got to Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Internal PDF Viewer -> Auto-recompile document on changes. To speed up compilation, go to Options -> configure TeXstudio -> Commands and change `-synctex=1` to `-synctex=-1`. This will deactivate compression of `.synctex` files.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a solution: Kile on Windows, see[KileOnWindows](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/kile/index.php?title=KileOnWindows).

The default version currently is a beta version with live preview, which I like very much.

Answer (score 2):

Emacs + AucTeX can do that, but especially on Windows, getting it to work can require hours of trial-and-error configuration, see [Problem getting preview to work in Auctex on Windows 7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39453/problem-getting-preview-to-work-in-auctex-on-windows-7).

Answer (score 1):

There is a program in the MacTex (and I assume TeXLive) distribution called LaTeXIT that may do what you want. It's probably available elsewhere as well.  You can type in snippets of latex code and click a button to see the rendering.  It's not really what you want, but if you want to try some code out, you can do so easily.  The program is used for people who just want to create a jpg or pdf of an equation for embedding in a web page, but could be used for previewing as well.

Comment: MacTeX also includes some additional software to TeXlive, including LaTeXit, which as far as I can see is only available for OS X.

Comment: LaTeXiT is **only** available for Mac and the author of the software has indicated that porting it to any other platform is more than unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a [live preview plugin](http://zohooo.github.io/quadview) for [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com) editor. It will show the preview of current paragraph in the upper right corner of WinEdt. Furthermore it will update the preview automatically if current paragraph has been changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I understood the question (TeX or LaTeX) but this site works quite well for LaTeX previews:

https://www.writelatex.com