# Which TeX editors are able to compile just a snippet of a .tex file?

Tags: compiling, editors, texshop, code-snippets

A friend of mine asked me whether `TeXShop` is able to compile just a snippet of a `.tex` file or not. More generally, one could ask which TeX editors are able to compile just a snippet of a `.tex` file? This question:

- is related to [Getting a live preview of TeX (on Windows) - for just a small snippet of code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34522/18401) but is Windows oriented,
- is partially answered in [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/18401) but:

  - its answers maybe aren't complete on this subject,
  - makes such information uneasy to find.

### Update

More precisely, I'm looking for pure TeX editors solutions that let the user select a region of a `.tex` file and compile just this region from the current `.tex` file (with its class, packages, personal macros, more generally its preamble). Just the names of such editors would be nice, how it is done would be the icing on the cake.

Comment: WinEdt certainly has or had this concept, but one has to start by deciding what the 'master' document for a snippet is, which itself sounds tricky.

Comment: Emacs + AUCTeX is available also on Windows.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. For the Mac, there is LaTeXit which is effectively a snippet editor. And of course you can use the `standalone` class to create snippets. But maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: any editor that has programmable customisation should be able to do this, basically copy the preamble of the current document, the current region and \end{document} into a temporary file and run latex.

Comment: the best solution is to use the *subfiles* package an make all the individual `*.tex` files subfiles of the `main.tex`. this solution works with any editor, but needs some care about the include path for resources if you organize your project in subfolders.

Comment: Are you asking for people simply to name editors where it is possible, or how it is done in the relevant editor? (It is pretty easy with Emacs + AUCTeX....)

Comment: @JosephWright In TeXstudio, it is not necessary to specify the 'master' file: you just select a region, run `Alt+P` and an image (built thanks to `dvi2png`) of the snippet compiled from the current file is added below this region.

Comment: @giordano I'm using myself `Emacs` + `AUCTeX` and its feature that lets you compile the selected region from the current file: very nice! Unfortunately, I wouldn't advise my friend to switch to Emacs (already too much work to help him with more usual tools :)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Agree but I'm looking for a builtin feature, especially because I don't own a Mac and cannot try to extend TeXShop :)

Comment: @jon Just the name could be enough. How it is done would be the icing on the cake :)

Comment: @AlanMunn If I'm right, the trouble with `LaTeXit` is that it can't compile code that requires non standard classes, packages or own macros.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle In fact, I'm looking for TeX editors based solution that let you leave the file content untouched. See what is possible e.g. with TeXstudio as written in my comment to Joseph.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Absolutely it can. You can create whatever preamble you like for a snippet. It's not automatic, of course.

Comment: @AlanMunn Okay. The drawback is that this needs several copy-paste actions: not very handy compared to other solutions that let you compile in place just a portion of your code, leaving the whole file untouched.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé *"I'm looking for TeX editors based solution"* as a "one man show" OK, but for those who do team work an editor independent solution might be more appropriate...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Indeed. The idea here is, for a single user, how to quickly compile just a fraction of a (rather long) document, in order to check its layout or whether the corresponding code is buggy or not.

Answer (score 28):

Amazingly enough, TeXShop *does* in fact have such a facility. The problem is that long-time users of it like myself are probably unaware of it.

It can be found under the Edit Menu -> Experiment

This menu will open a window which you can copy a snippet of the currently open document.  When you press the Typeset button on the window, it will show the result in a small preview window:

[image: TeXShop Experiment sample]

Comment: Nice to having excavated this feature! Nevertheless, too bad it requires a copy-paste: I guess it should be possible for `TeXShop` to do the same job just by selecting the region and running Edit Menu → Experiment. I'll post a feature request to Richard Koch.

Comment: Richard Koch nicely accepted my feature request: many thanks to him! :) No need to copy paste anymore (when TeXShop update will be available, starting tomorrow): if you select text and then go to Edit Menu → Experiment, the selected text will be automatically copied in the Experiment (text) window, the layout of which can be controlled with "Typeset" button which brings up the typeset window. If nothing is selected when you go to Edit Menu → Experiment, you'll get the previous contents (or an empty page if this is its first use in the session).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé Great! Yes Dick is extremely responsive to user suggestions.

Answer (score 23):

With Emacs and AUCTeX, it is as simple as highlighting the portion of the text you want to compile and then hitting `C-c C-r` (or `M-x TeX-command-region`).

The command tries to be 'smart' about it, so if you do `C-c C-r RET C-c C-r RET` (i.e., run the same command on the same section twice) it will first compile, then, second, open a viewer for resultant PDF. (By default, called `_region_.pdf`).

In order to selection the region, the easiest way is to move the cursor to the start (or end) or the desired region, hit `C-SPC` (or `M-x set-mark-command`) to set the mark, then move it to the end (or start) of the region. Then hit `C-c C-r RET` to compile that selection.

Note that this also creates a file called `_region_.tex`.

Consider this file (called, say, `fulldoc.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[2]

% imagine trying to compile only this list (note you must do the whole environment)
\begin{itemize}
\item More lorem
\item More ipsum
\end{itemize}
% end of region being compiled
\lipsum[3]

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

This would create the following file and run (in this case) `pdflatex` on it:

```
\message{ !name(fulldoc.tex)}\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\message{ !name(fulldoc.tex) !offset(3) }
\begin{itemize}
\item More lorem
\item More ipsum
\end{itemize}

\message{ !name(fulldoc.tex) !offset(5) }

\end{document}
```

Doing `C-r RET` again will open a viewer of `_region_.pdf` Of course, you could also compile the `_region_.tex` file from the shell, etc.

Note: if you mark a new region, it will do the same thing all over again, but use the same `_region_` base filename.

**Note** As **giordano** notes, starting with [version 11.89](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Changes.html#Changes) of AUCTeX, it is now possible to compile a single section (not necessarily a single '`\section`') of your file. From the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Starting-a-Command.html#Starting-a-Command):

> Command: `LaTeX-command-section`
>
> (`C-c C-z`) Query the user for a command, and apply it to the current section (or part, chapter, subsection, paragraph, or
>   subparagraph). What makes the current section is determined by
>   `LaTeX-command-section-level` which can be enlarged/shrunken using
>   `LaTeX-command-section-change-level` (`C-c M-z`). The given numeric prefix
>   arg is added to the current value of `LaTeX-command-section-level`. By
>   default, `LaTeX-command-section-level` is initialized with the current
>   document’s `LaTeX-largest-level`. The buffer contents are written into
>   the region file, after extracting the header and trailer from the
>   master file. The command is then actually run on the region file. See
>   `TeX-command-region` for details.

In essence, what AUCTeX does is the same as in my example above. The advantage is that you don't need to explicitly mark a portion of text that you want to compile.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you can also automatically run LaTeX on the current section without even selecting it, using `C-c C-z`: https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Starting-a-Command.html#Starting-a-Command

Comment: Whoa! Never even noticed that option before! Will edit.

Answer (score 12):

Kile has this feature. It is called `QuickPreview`. I've never used it before, but I tested it in a minimal example and it seems to work.

I tested with my answer to another question:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  pics/multimeter/.style={
    code={
      \tikzset{
        multi meter/.cd,
        #1,
      }
      \begin{scope}[]
        \coordinate (\multimetername-o) at (0,0);
        \foreach \i/\j/\k/\l in {A/o/south/A,V/o/north/V,TL/mA.west/east/HI,BL/mV.west/east/HI,TR/mA.east/west/LO,BR/mV.east/west/LO} \node (\multimetername-m\i) [multi meter/label, anchor=\k] at (\multimetername-\j) {\l};
        \foreach \i in {TL.west,TR.east,BL.south,BR.south} \node [circle, fill, inner sep=1.25pt] at (\multimetername-m\i) {};
        \node [draw, fit=(\multimetername-mTR) (\multimetername-mBL)] {};
      \end{scope}
    }
  },
  multi meter/.search also={/tikz,/circuitikz},
  multi meter/.cd,
  label/.style={font=\sffamily, align=center, transform shape, pic actions},
  name/.store in=\multimetername,
  name=multimeter,
}
\begin{circuitikz}[american, cute inductors]
  \draw
  (0,0) node[anchor = east] {C} coordinate (C)
  (0,2) node[anchor = east] {B} coordinate (B)
  (0,4) node[anchor = east] {A} coordinate (A)
  pic [rotate=-90] at (3,0) {multimeter={name=M}}

  (A) to [short] ++(2,0)
  (B) to [short] ++(6,0)
  (C) to [short] ++(2,0)
  (1.5,0) to[short,*-] ++(0,1.2)
  to[short] ++(1,0)
  -| (M-mTL.west)
  (M-mBR.south) to[short] ++(-1.25,0) coordinate (c) to [short,-*] (B -| c)
  ;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Highlighting the contents of the `document` environment (but not the environment itself or the preamble) and choosing `Build > QuickPreview > Selection` typeset the selection.

As far as I can ascertain, the way this works is that Kile tries to identify the preamble by looking for the first line containing `\documentclass` for the start of the preamble and the `\begin{document}` line to figure out where the preamble ends. It copies the preamble to a file in a temporary directory called `preview.tex`, along with the selection, wrapped in a `document` environment. It then typesets this document and displays the result, if successful.

I tested the `QuickPreview > Selection` option. Other `QuickPreview` options include `Environment`, `Subdocument` and `Maths group`.