# LyX Preview Functionality in Editors

Tags: lyx

I recently tried LyX and although I didn't like the way it works (you have to press buttons for everything), I liked so much the preview. The best thing was that when you write a `\frac` it expands it and lets you see the nominator and denominator or when you write `\sum` etc.

I was wondering if there is a way to have that functionality in any online editor or generally in other editors.

Comment: The functionality of any editor depends on the developer(s), so there is no general solution I think. There are editors that do this though, I think Kile and Emacs both have it. Overleaf as well, if you turn on the Rich text feature.

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34522/getting-a-live-preview-of-tex-on-windows-for-just-a-small-snippet-of-code Edit: Oops, one thing: were you talking about the actual preview feature of LyX, or just the standard view of math mode? I was talking about the former, where the code is generated into a small image which is displayed instead of the standard view.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am talking about the standard view where you write not the output. :)

Comment: Sorry, I was in any case not talking about the output, but (in LyX) Tools --> Preferences --> Display --> Instant preview. But still, my first comment applies, I don't think there is any general solution to this.